# Есть ли какие-либо ошибки в следующем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, запятые, грамматика

Как понять, что Бог дал взамен тому, чего не дал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведнёом Вами предложении вместо родительного падежа ("взамен тоГО") используется дательный ("взамен тоМУ").

Ошибки здесь нет, но для моего уха это звучит слегка архаично.

В современном русском языке чаще сказали бы "Бог дал взамен тоГО, чего не дал" или "Бог дал взамен тоГО, чТО не дал".

Скажем,

"По житейским меркам, Бог в этой жизни многого ему недодал. Но взамен того, чего не дал, дал много другого."

Можно, конечно сказать "Но взамен тоМУ, чего не дал, дал много другого", но  с моей точки зрения, это звучит не вполне современно.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ!